# Can I have a path in my Azure Node/Express app load a static site from blob storage without redirecting?

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I have a Node/Express web service running on Azure. Currently, I'm essentially serving up an entire static site from one endpoint (`http://domain/userguide/`) on that service. I would like to move the site over to blob storage but keep the same path while leaving the rest of the service intact. Is it possible?

I realize I could redirect to the blob storage path, but I would prefer the paths remain as they were previously while the user is navigating the static site.

Comment: have you tried using the express static middleware with a changed path?

Comment: @mvuajua I was under the impression I could only use express.static to point to locations on the local file system. Is it possible to do something like `app.use('/userguide', express.static('http://blobdomain/staticsite'));`?

Comment: not sure, that's why I was asking if you tried, but probably not, you're right. I'm not sure whether what you're asking is possible, but if we're talking static sites only you could use [request](https://github.com/request/request) to get the contents and display them